# Is it bad alternator or starter? Camry ‘05 173k miles..

Tags: alternator, starter, camry, cold-start, cold-weather

I started my car after two days of cold weather, around 20 F. After heating my engine for about 15 minuets I turned ignition off.  After that it does not start, it start to crank but dies off well before that, it makes clicking sound and lights on dashboard flashes.

I tried to jump start with to powerful batteries of truck and dodge caravan but it did not work. 
I always use full synthetic 5w-30 high milage oil and just week before I had changed oil. Oil level is near full.

Here is a dropbox link to video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qu96vwcug7llbp8/camry05-prob-starting.mov?dl=0

Is  alternator or starter bad? Please help.

Comment: Cold weather is very hard on batteries. It gets worse with age. How old is your battery?

Comment: @CharlieRB it is about 2.5 yr old. Its some crapy brand called DieHard.

Comment: Might be going bad. Worth having it tested to see if it is the issue. Might even still be under warranty (depending which one you have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That video was very helpful.  You have either a *low* battery, a bad connection to the battery, or a bad connection to the starter.  Since jumping from another vehicle (the other vehicle was running, right?) wasn't working, it could be a poor electrical connection.  Metal expands and contracts with temperature changes so cold or extremely hot temps can make these issues show up.

If the battery is very low, either the battery is internally damaged and will not work as it should, or the alternator is bad and not recharging the battery.

One of the easiest things to do is swap batteries with another car.  This will tighten the battery connections and eliminate the battery as a cause.  If it still doesn't start, check connections to the starter.  Once the car is started, you can use a voltmeter to see if the battery is being charged (should be 13-14v when car is running).

Comment: Thank you @JPhi1618. I removed battery and took it to AutoZone for testing and charging.  After charging it worked just fine, though AutoZone guy advised me to replace battery.